# LINQ group by, getting the latest results

Tags: c#, sql, linq, group-by

I'm fairly new to LINQ, so this might be an easy peasy for some of you, but I've been ripping my hair out for quite a while now :)

Scenario :
I have box containing 3 Hardware Modules that have diffrent ports.
Using Serial comunication i extract data from the modules into a SQL table called CurrentData_Tables
So each time a unit gets produced, my program will write an entry into the table saying how big the sum is.
Let me try and visualize it.

```
BoxID, ModuleID, PortNumber, Value, Time
1,     0A,       1,          {Value},     {Date}
```

The time is excatly the same on the readings for that specific module, so i imagined i could group by the data that is constant and then just get the latest.
This is what i got up with so far :

```
SQLdbDataContext sqlDB = new SQLdbDataContext();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
var Latest = from q in sqlDB.CurrentData_Tabels
             group q by new
             {
                 q.BoxID,
                 q.ModuleID,
                 q.PortNumber,
                 q.Time
             }
             into groupOrder
             select new
             {
                 BoxID = groupOrder.Key.BoxID,
                 ModuleID = groupOrder.Key.ModuleID,
                 Portnumber = groupOrder.Key.PortNumber,
                 Time = groupOrder.Key.Time
             };
```

And that's perfectly fine, i get all the results i want... And more, i dont need to know that the reading on module 0A, port 1 had counted to 2 before the latest entry of 3..
Is this understandable ? , If not please let me try to explain it again :)

Doing a > to get the largest sum wouldn't work, since i also have statuses that triggers on bool values, 1 means there's an alarm present on the machine, and 0 means all is OK!

Comment: What counts as the "latest"? If we assume that the data in the database can be returned in *any* order, how should we know which value to use?

Comment: The ones with the latest date stamp.

Comment: Which is the date stamp? The Time field? Because you're already grouping by that... it's not really clear what's going on. If you could give some example data with more rows, and what you want the result to be, that would really help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the Time field from the group expression and use a Max in the Select new.